# Speech Services STT- Possible to Link Request to Result?

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I have a use case where a mobile app records a long series of commands. Each command is a short, single word (or number). They can happen quickly one right after the other, but the use case does not care if it takes several seconds to get results back from the Cognitive server. It is currently being implemented as discrete asynchronous requests rather than streaming (seems to be more reliable for us).

Since results are coming back async, I see no easy way to map the result back to its corresponding request (and ultimately the app command). Can I embed a unique ID somewhere that will get passed back to me? Is there some other option?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the SDK? 
If you do recognizeOnce you get the result from the audio as a call result (synchronous)

If you do continuousrecognition there is currently no way to tag the audio segment.

Comment: I am on Xamarin using the excellent Xamarin.Cognitive.Speech Nuget. I believe it is using the REST API under the hood. Either way, I need asynchronous handling for our use case (we need to send new requests before the previous may have been fully transcribed). I realized though that I can (I think) just lean on C# lambdas to create a unique ID and still have it around when the call eventually returns. Seems like it would be very useful to be able to explicitly tag requests though.